# Click not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ipad

I have the following problem I have a

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="/">main page</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will work on any desktop browser but it won't click on Ipad/Iphone and Android.

Comment: This isn't Android. Why is this with the "android" tag?

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't work in mobile browsers?  If so then the problem is *definitely* being caused by something else.  Are you using a library like jQuery UI, for example?

Comment: @luiscosta the browser is on android device that is why

Comment: I am not using any jquery plugin @Archer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue is related to devices (Ipad/Iphone, android phones) as you mentioned.
the touchend event call event.stopPropagation() for that you was not able to achive the action.
To solve your problem you have 2 solutions:
-do not put your code inside

```
<ul> and <li> and the code will be like that 

<div>
   <a href="/"> main page</a>
</div>
```

-The second solution create a new directive called eventStop

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="/" stop-event="touchend">main page</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

and the directive is

```
.directive('stopEvent', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on(attr.stopEvent, function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```